# str_replace with amp; doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm using php7 for my project, trying to replace a string "X & Y" with strreplace as follows

```
$out=str_replace("X amp; Y","other string",$out);
```

But the string is never replaced, tried also using & symbol itself but it doesn't work too.

Comment: I believe it's `&amp;` not `amp;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
  $out=str_replace("X &amp; Y","other string",$out);
```

http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html

> ampersand `&amp;  &#38;   &#x26;  &   &   &`

Comment: not working too, i'v tried php7 it works, but my server is 5.5.9

Comment: well when you don't include the value of `$out` in your post, one can only guess.